# How to pass from model to controller Ruby on Rails

Tags: model, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I am unsure how to call a model method from a controller

In Event controller query is ran in

```
 class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def self.all_published()
       events = 'SELECT  user_id FROM events'
       where("dotw = DAYNAME(curdate())")
    end
  end
```

Page_controller

```
  def index
    @published_posts = Event.all_published.paginate()
  end
```

View

```
  <% if @published_posts.any? %>
     <ol class="microposts">
       <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @published_posts %>
    </ol>
    <%= will_paginate @published_posts %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails follow the "fat model, skinny controller" convention. This means that you should put your business logic, such as queries, inside your models.

In your case, the `all_published` method should go in your `Event` model such as:

```
class Event
  def self.all_published
    where('your sql query here')
  end
end
```

Then call with:

```
Event.all_published
```

Rails controllers should only be responsible of rendering / redirecting and settings views variables.